# Разделение элементов списка запятой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет, есть проблема, не могу понять как преобразовать список на выходе -

1. чтобы он содержал числа (в моём случае, я так понимаю, из-за `.join`, числа в моём списке формата `str`)
2. разделить эти числа в списке запятыми

я уже и пытался в `.join` подпихнуть `,`  - получал ошибку: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`
и выходной список перевести в int, короче, я не могу понять уже, что мне сделать.

Большое спасибо за ответ!

Вот код:

```
import random
def get_random_value():
    list = ('1234567890')
    value = random.sample(list, 4) # смешивает числа из списка и выводит (в данном случае) 4 числа, даже сам создает список
    while value[0] == '0':
        random.shuffle(value)
    list_value = int(', '.join(value))
    list = []
    list.append(list_value)

    return list

print(get_random_value(), (type(get_random_value()))) #тут печатаю значение и проверяю тип выходных данных
```

Comment: не называйте переменные list пожалуйсто. и покажите результат, который ожидаете на выходе.

Comment: ожидаю получить: [1, 2, 3, 4] а почему не называть list?)

Comment: попробуйте a=list(map(int,list('123456'))) где лист это имя встроеной функции, а не имя вашей переменной.

Comment: Большое спасибо!! получилось!
 Добавлю решение сюда

Comment: `a=list(map(int, '123456'))`. Внутренний `list` был лишний.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо "Интик" за помощь, вот решение проблемы:

```
import random
def get_random_value():
    a = list(map(int, list('1234567890')))
    value = random.sample(a, 4) # смешивает числа из списка и выводит (в данном случае) 4 числа, даже сам создает список
    while value[0] == 0:
        random.shuffle(value)

    return value

print(get_random_value(), (type(get_random_value())))
```